# I can't import voice

Tags: python

My code:

```
import pyttsx3
import speech_recognition as sr
def speak():
 'engine = pyttsx3.init()'
 'engine.say(text)'
 'engine.runAndzWait()'
'speak("Hy Hussnain")'
```

I'm getting this error, but can't resolve it:

> TypeError: speak() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given

Answer (score 1):

You've defined a function speak() but you haven't said that it accepts any arguments- there's nothing inside the brackets.

So later on when you say 'speak("Hy Hussnain")' it tries to call the function and give it "Hy Hussnain", but you've not defined it with arguments above, so you get the error.